# CakePHP: multiple INSERT operations based on Form Input

Tags: php, cakephp

**Conditions:**
1. Let's say, I have a table like this:

```
create table users (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  first_name varchar(255),
  last_name varchar(255),
  email varchar(255)
);
```

2. And I have a simple form `users/add` with 2 input fields - user and email - and submit button

What I want to do is the following: I want to insert Form data based on what is typed inside **user field**. I mean if I type a word **all**, cakePHP will insert **the same** email for **all** users in that table. If I type only one digit (i.e. id), cakePHP will insert email only for a user with this id.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can learn [ask] and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some controller code that might help you out.

```
function add()
{
    if ($this->request->data['inputName'] == 'all') {
        $this->User->updateAll(
            array('User.email' => value)
        );
    } else {
        $this->User->id = $this->request->data['inputName'];
        $this->User->saveField('email', value);
    }
}
```

[saveField](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false)

[updateAll](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions)

Comment: It helped me. Thanks!